# nhibernate with asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate

hai guys,
          I am new to nhibernate please suggest some article to start knowing about nhibernate with asp.net mvc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd look at [the documentation on NHibernate.info](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/)

Answer (score 2):

You should propably look at this site: http://www.sharparchitecture.net/

quote from the site: "Pronounced "Sharp Architecture," this is a solid architectural foundation for rapidly building maintainable web applications leveraging the ASP.NET MVC framework with NHibernate. The primary advantage to be sought in using any architectural framework is to decrease the code one has to write while increasing the quality of the end product."